# Error When upload iphone app to appstore

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

When we try to upload a new app to Apple's App Store we get the following error in Application Loader and in `Xcode` also:

```
ERROR ITMS-9000: "This bundle is invalid. New apps and app updates submitted to the App Store
must be built with public (GM) versions of Xcode 5 and iOS 7 SDK.
 Do not submit apps built with
    beta software." at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset
```

Comment: Are you trying to submit code compiled with Xcode 6?

Comment: You cannot upload any app using the beta versions of the Xcode. Please check the version of Xcode you are using for submission of your app on App Store.

Answer (score 1):

You might be using beta of Xcode and targeting to iOS 8. Try using Xcode 5.x and submit

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile, archive and send the app with XCode 5. Xcode 6 is not yet out as public release so it gives you that error.